# Updating certain nodes' style in d3js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

whats the simplest way to update the style of nodes, that are already drawn ?
In this case, the layout is created, with all the links, nodes - perfect. Then an array is passed to the directive and if the node name is in that array, I want to change its colour.

example:

```
var names = ["tom","john"]; // this data comes in...


                d3.select("node").select("circle").style("fill", function (d) {
                   // I check if the node name is in array, if so change its colour to green.
                    if (names.indexOf(d.name) > -1) {
                        return "green";
                    } else
                        return "red";

                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a selection [`filter`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter)

```
d3.selectAll("node").selectAll("circle")
  .filter(function(d){
    return names.indexOf(d.name) < 0;
  })
  .style("fill", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

ahmohamed's method is good.  Another alternative: When you're building the page, add the names as values of `id` or as an additional `class` for each node.  Then you can select the element you want using that id or class, perhaps with a compound CSS selector.  For example if you make the names `id`s, you can do:

```
d3.selectAll("node").selectAll("#tom").style("fill", "green");
```

Here "#tom" refers to all DOM elements with `id="tom"`.  If there are things other than circles with "tom" as id, this should work:

```
d3.selectAll("node").selectAll("circle#tom").style("fill", "green");
```

That says to get `circle`s with `id="tom"`.

(It may be possible to combine `#tom` and `#john` with some kind of OR operator in the selector.  I'm not sure.)